# Issue retrieving package name of android apps

Tags: java, android, package

I'm trying to get the package name of multiple apps that have been mapped. I want to access them using `ResolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName` but I am having issues, notably with `activityInfo` as Java keeps informing me that a `"static method cannot be referenced from a static context."` I'm assuming I need to create a new object and then access the package name of each app but I just don't know how to go about it.

Here's part of the code where I want to print this information:

```
public void printPackageName() {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ResolveInfo>> entries = selectedMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry<String, ResolveInfo> entry = entries.next();
         String pname = ResolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
         System.out.println("App info: " + pname);
         }
    }
```

I've seen a solution to a similar problem where the user wanted the package name of the home directory. In their case the issue was resolved with the code below. I'm assuming that I could potentially modify this code for my purposes but I'm not using intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,  PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
String currentHomePackage = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ResolveInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) is a class. You need an instance to access `activityInfo`. Also, [`ActivityInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html) does not contain a member named `packageName`, but you probably wanted `resolvePackageName`, such as:

```
while (entries.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry<String, ResolveInfo> entry = entries.next();
     String pname = entry.getValue().resolvePackageName;
     System.out.println("App info: " + pname);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I need an instance of ResolveInfo to access activityInfo? Or that I need any instance of what I'm working with in general to access activityInfo?

Comment: You need the *instance* of `ResolveInfo`, which you have placed in the map. You get that through `getValue()` as shown. The way you had it, you'd iterate the map entries, but not do anything with them, and instead tried to access non-existing static fields on the class `ResolveInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I appreciate it. I'll give that solution a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Well, post the code where you *populate* the map. Looks like you're not putting any values in there.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I was able to get it to work. I actually needed to set my string to     entry.getValue().activityInfo.packageName; After that, it worked flawlessly.